# SQL, order by article language with priorities for English then French

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a muli language website and I have articles they may or may not be in all the languages the website is in. Also the user has the possibility to register and choose a preferred language.

My problem is the following, when displaying an article I would like for it to display it in this way : if the user is logged in then display the language he has chosen, if an article is not in his language try and display it in English else if it doesn't exist French, then German etc.

This is my article table :

```
news_id |  lang  |   title  |  text  |
      1 |    en  |  News en |  bla.. |
      1 |    fr  |  News fr |  bla.. |
      2 |    en  |   New en |  bla.. |
      3 |    fr  |   Nws fr |  bla.. |
```

I have no idea how to do this in mysql.

And I hope you can understand my problem, I don't really know how to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Gordon's answer is technically correct I would recommend to you a slightly different approach: You could add another table (let's call it `language`) that defines a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) over the set of languages used.

```
        language
--------------------------
|  id  |  name  |  rank  |
--------------------------
    1      en       1
    2      fr       2
    3      de       3
    4      nl       4
```

This table's data set now determines the partial order over the languages of your site. To use it in your queries you would do something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT a.*
    FROM article a
       , language b
   WHERE a.id = [xxx]
     AND a.lang = b.name
ORDER BY (a.lang = [session.lang]) DESC,
         b.rank ASC
   LIMIT 1
```

**What's the point you ask?**
Well, set up this way, once you need to change the partial order over the set of languages to something different, you won't have to update your queries to reflect that change. Granted, this won't be much of a hassle with just a couple of queries, but once you build up a few dozens of language aware queries it bites you in the foot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join in to the user preferences table, to get the desired language.  And then use that information in the order by:

```
select a.*
from articles a cross join
     (select up.*
      from UserPreferences up
      where up.userid = <whatever you want>
     ) up
order by (case when a.lang = up.prefland then 0
               when a.lang = 'en' then 1
               when a.lang = 'fr' then 2
               else 3 end) asc
```

This particular order by does the preferred language first, then English, then French.  To just get the preferred first, remove the second two "when" clauses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I won't be using the join since the language variable is actually stored in a session variable.